# Trigger to remove text before and after

Tags: trigger, split

I want to split text out of c.Description to populate a custom field Response_Name__c

c.Description is

```
"Sent on : 1/3/2018 9:24:00 PM 
 By User: Julie Trigger
 Comment"
```

I want Response_Name__c to result in "Julie Trigger"

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This site isn't a coding service, but rather a place to help people overcome problems and become better programmers and admins by focusing on very specific and tightly-scoped issues. If you're new to Salesforce (or writing triggers), Trailhead is much better suited than this site is. There is a [trailhead module on Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers).

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to match using multiline mode in a pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?m)By User: (.+?)$');
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
  record.Response_Name__c = null;
  if(record.Description != null) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(record.Description);
    if(m.find()) {
      record.Response_Name__c = m.group(1);
    }
  }
}
```

This regular expression means the following:

```
(?m)                  Enable Multiline Mode
    By User:          Literal text before our match
             (   )    Capture group #1
              .       Match any character
               +      Match at least once (so at least one of any character)
                ?     Makes the match "non-greedy" (match as few characters as possible)
                  $   Match end of line (with M flag, means \n character)
```

Comment: I'm terrible with regex so I was just fartin around, I modified your patter to **By User: (.+?)\s*$** so that it strips any potential whitespace chars between the end of the name and the end of the line from the group. Not a big change but someone might find some value to it.

Comment: @gNerb You can, but it's not necessary, because fields strip leading and trailing spaces when you save them to the database.